# How should I implement subtypes of a Message class in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, subtyping

I'm sure this is a basic OOP question -- I'm designing a message-passing system where there are several entirely distinct message formats, but I want them all to be able to be placed on a PriorityBlockingQueue.  My first thought was to define an `abstract class Message` and then define subclasses extending Message for each of the message types.  But this means that, at the receiving end, the message processor needs to identify the subclass in order to know how to process the contents of the message.  And the only way I know of doing this is with `.instanceof()` or `Class.` and it somehow doesn't seem right.

As Scott Meyers writes,

> Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is
>   of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do
>   something else," slap yourself.

(He goes on to make the point that, in polymorphism, you should have the same method names having different implementations for each subclass.  I don't see how I can make that idea work in my case - the message types themselves are utterly unrelated.)

For the sake of discussion, here are my message types:

- ConsoleMessage, identifying a ConsoleObject and an ObjectState.
- CardReaderRequestMessage, not containing anything but simply requesting "next card"
- CardReaderMessage, containing a byte[80] card image and a Last Card indicator
- CardPunchMessage, containing a byte[80] card image
- CardPunchResponseMessage, not containing anything but signifying that the card image was copied to the punch buffer

I believe I have to know what kind of message I'm dealing with, so I suspect I should not be using polymorphic Messages.  How should I design this properly?

===== EDIT to raise a follow-up question =====

I was trying to find a way to use a polymorphic Message without having, at some point, to identify its subclass.  The suggested approach was to override a `process()` method in each subclass.  Here's my (simplified) abstract Message and two subclasses:

```
public abstract class Message {

    public abstract void process() {
        // subclasses of Message implement this
    }

    public static class ConsoleMessage extends Message {
        private int obj;
        private int state;
        public ConsoleMessage(int x, int y) {
            obj = x;
            state = y;
        }
        @Override
        public void process() {
            // do something with obj and state?
        }

    public static class CardReaderMessage extends Message {
        private byte[] card;
        private boolean lastCardIndicator;
        public CardReaderMessage(byte[] c, boolean lc) {
            card = c;
            lastCardIndicator = lc;
        }
        @Override
        public void process() {
            // do something with card and lastCardIndicator
        }
}
```

There is one queue per thread for all "inbound" Messages.  Suppose my thread needs to wait for a message from the console to "resume", but meanwhile should receive and process other message types:

```
waitForResumeMessage() {
    while (true) { // the following will block until a msg arrives
        Message msg = inboundMessageQueue.receiveMessage();
        msg.process();
```

But now what?  Some implementation of process() has moved some data somewhere, but ultimately I need to be able to write:

```
        if // msg was ConsoleMessage "resume" command
            return;  // .. from waitForResumeMessage()
    } // else iterate until another message
}
```

Which basically means finding out what class 'msg' belongs to.

Am I approaching this all wrong?  I realize that "waiting" is not really appropriate in an "event-driven" model, but this is a long-running background worker.  Perhaps the idea of using process() is more useful for changing the state of an FSM that's guiding an event-driven thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good, you should indeed start with either an abstract class or an interface called Message, and this interface should be something like this:

```
     public interface Message {
     void process();
     //some other methods
}

public class MessageType1  implements Message {
    @Override
    public void process() {
      //My special way to process this message
}
}
```

This way the receiving end only has to receive something that IS A Message i.e. implements your Message interface, and it doesn't really care what type of particular message all it cares is that it responds to process, so you can just implement how each particular message should be processed there.

Comment: But for this to be a good design this does assume that `process()` is the Message's single responsibility, and it seems the OP is saying that isn't the case.

Comment: @Mark Peters That is true, but he could declare as many methods as needed on the interface.

Comment: True, but likely not without violating the single responsibility principle or separation of concerns, which I would argue are much more important to follow than avoiding a "switch" design smell.

Comment: I have to admit that I hadn't made the mental leap from Animal.talk() to Message.process().  Really, that's all it needs to be able to do, I think.  I appreciate all the feedback about template methods, parametric polymorphism, and even annotation -- these to me are relatively advanced topics, but I'm looking forward to getting the hang of Design Patterns soon.

Answer (score 2):

You're not crazy.  That argument:

> Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else," slap yourself.

is only one side of the story.  The other side of the story is that it's just as (if not more) vital to maintain separation of concerns.  A common example is that you shouldn't add presentation code to your model just because that's where it can be handled polymorphically.  Unfortunately the Java language doesn't give much help in accomplishing both ideals simultaneously.

There are many ways to keep "parallel but decoupled" code.  The [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is one, as is a big switch or if-instance-of block.  Another option is a `Map` of concrete class to concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is template methods. What that means is that you define in Message methods that the receiving end would want to call using the same interface but based on the type of actual object the overridden method in any of the types of Messages would actually be called.

Comment: What does this look like in Java?

Comment: Pretty much OscarMk's answer above. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: Ah, I was confused by your statement "what you want is not polymorphism."  Oscar's example would quite definitely be an example of polymorphism since the receiving end would only be dealing with `Message`s.

Comment: Fixed. What I had in mind was http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Parametric_Polymorphism

Comment: @Murali: I can't understand your answer; specifically the sentence beginning "What that means...".  Could you try rephrasing it into several shorter sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the already proposed solutions I would like to mention that you could do it without any interfaces or abstract classes.

One could create his own annotion, which contains the information where the message object can be processed.

At implementation time:
You annotate your classes accordingly.

At runtime:
When you pop the next element from the queue you could inspect the annotation and call the implementation that is able to process the current instance.